# OpenCV imresize crashing program

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm working with OpenCV in Python 2.7.5 and I'm having a weird issue where resizing my image makes my program crash. Here is my code that causing an issue:

```
def NN(tiles, testData):
        img1 = cv.imread(tile)
        img1 = cv.resize(img1,(0,0), fx = 0.2, fy = 0.2)

        #Create pair to pass into findInlier as one
        #argument (for multiprocessing
        pairs = [(img1, img2) for img2 in testData]
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12)
        inliers = p.map(findInlier,pairs)
```

`tiles` is a string to an image and `testData` is a list of OpenCV images. Running this code above gives me the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 108, in <module>
    main()
  File "./main.py", line 104, in main
    NN(tiles, images)
  File "./main.py", line 75, in NN
    inliers = p.map(findInlier,pairs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

However if I remove the following line `img1 = cv.resize(img1,(0,0), fx = 0.2, fy = 0.2)` everything works perfectly fine. I have no idea why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking the type of `img1` immediately after calling `cv.resize`? How about manually checking the results of applying `findInlier` to `pairs` in a loop so you can find the pair that throws that error?

Comment: doesn't the stacktrace say, that the pairs in `inliers = p.map(findInlier,pairs)` were None ?

Comment: Hmmm...so I changed the size so that the image wouldn't be so small (from 0.2 to 0.5) but as soon I do that I get a pop up window error saying "Python quit unexpectedly while using the libopencv_core.2.4.dylib plug-in." Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: Just one thing to try: Can you display the image and make sure it is properly loaded?